# Change href to django iterated object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a template with a formset:

```
<form method='post' id="data_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ my_formset.management_form }}
    <table>
      ...
      <tbody>
        {% for form in my_formset %}
          <tr>
            {% for field in form %}
              {% if 'inventory_number' in field.auto_id %}
                <td>
                  <a href="{% url 'invent:update_item' pk %}" class="update-link">
                    {{ field.value }}
                  </a>
                </td>
              {% else %}
                <td>{{ field }}</td>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
```

Since the field "inventory_number" is supposed to be immutable anyway, I want it to link to the `UpdateView` of this item. I can get `pk` for this item with JS:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('update-link')
  for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    let link_row = links[i].parentNode.parentNode
    let item_id = link_row.lastElementChild.childNodes[1].attributes.value.value
  };
```

Now how do I pass this `item_id` form the script to django `{% url 'invent:update_item' pk %}`? Or maybe there's a better way to do it all together.

**UPDATE**

Fixed it like this:

```
            {% for field in form %}
              {% if '-id' in field.auto_id %}
                {% if field.value %}
                  <td>
                    <a href="{% url 'invent:update_item' field.value %}">
                      <img src="{% static 'img/edit.png' %}">
                      {{ field }}
                    </a>
                  </td>
                {% else %}
                  {{ field }}
                {% endif %}
              {% else %}
                <td> {{ field }}</td>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
```

Not exactly what I wanted, but it will do.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try field.value instead of pk in {% url %} tag?

```
{% if 'inventory_number' in field.auto_id %}
    <td>
      <a href="{% url 'invent:update_item' field.value %}" class="update-link">
        {{ field.value }}
      </a>
    </td>
{% else %}
```

Comment: ```field.value``` is not a pk for this object. It's just a string

Comment: But If I use hidden id input instead as a link, that should actually work,